# Passing variables from python server to HTML using Flask

Tags: python, html, pandas, flask

I'm looking to build a basic website using `Flask` to display predictions from a python machine learning project. I have the following file structure:

```
project/
    static/
        style.css
        script.js
    templates/
        index.html
    server.py
```

And I'm looking to pass the predictions from my `server.py` into my `index.html`

The predictions are stored in a `Pandas DataFrame` in the following format:

```
      P1     P2
0     60     40
1     26     74
```

I've managed to pass this data into my `index.html` with the following code in my `server.py` file:

```
a = df['P1'][0]
b = df['P2'[0]
c = df['P1'][1]
d = df['P2'[1]

@app.route('/')
def pass_data():
    return render_template('index.html', a=a, b=b, c=c, d=d)
```

In reality I have far more predictions I wish to display in my `index.html`. So my question is, is there a better, more efficient way to pass data from my `DataFrame` into my `index.html`, as opposed to defining each one individually and passing them in the `return` command of the `pass_data()` function.

Appreciate any recommendations, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about passing the entire dataframe?

In the python file

```py
return render_template('index.html', df=df)
```

Inside `body` tag inside `index.html`

```py
{{ df.to_html() | safe }}
```